# How to use sfdx force:data:tree:export to export CPQ Bundle Product for import into a new scratch org?

Tags: salesforcedx, data-export, scratch-org, junction-object

For starters I am trying to only export set of Products, Feature and Options that comprise a single bundle Product, but having problems because Product Option object has two lookup relationships to Product and one to Feature. 
I don't mind an approach with multiple exports and a plan modification step, but I was not able to figure one out yet.

```
SELECT 
Id, 
Name, 
ProductCode,
IsActive,
(SELECT Id, Name, SBQQ__Number__c, SBQQ__MinOptionCount__c FROM SBQQ__Features__r),
(SELECT Id, Name, SBQQ__Number__c, SBQQ__Type__c FROM SBQQ__OptionalFor__r),
(SELECT Id, Name, SBQQ__Number__c, SBQQ__Type__c FROM SBQQ__Options__r)
FROM Product2 ORDER BY Id ASC
```

Referencing Options twice in a single query throws an error, which I was almost expecting:

```
gkibilov$ sfdx force:data:tree:export --outputdir /CfgData --plan --query /CfgSOQL/bundle.soql
ERROR running force:data:tree:export:  Overriding SBQQ__ProductOption__c reference for a0k56000007vOJJAA2: existing SBQQ__ProductOption__cRef1, incoming SBQQ__ProductOption__cRef12
```

Trying to think of an alternative where I could export:

1. Product (root only) + Features + Options (that are not referencing
   any Futures)
2. Features + Options
3. Options + Products (referenced by these Options) <- Cant figure this out

Basically this is a good old junction object export related question with a complication of junction of different records from the same Object, Product in addition to a second parent, Feature.

- Solution:

Figured it out. Looks like it is possible to reference sibling and parent records:

```
SELECT Id, Name, ProductCode, IsActive, 
(SELECT Id, Name, SBQQ__Number__c, SBQQ__MinOptionCount__c FROM SBQQ__Features__r), 
(SELECT Id, Name, SBQQ__Number__c, SBQQ__Type__c, SBQQ__Feature__c, SBQQ__OptionalSKU__c FROM SBQQ__Options__r) 
FROM Product2 ORDER BY Id DESC
```